# c#Listview:How to create Columns without header

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I have Listview on WinForm

I need to have two columns but without headers, How do i do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think ListView.HeaderStyle = ColumnHeaderStyle.None should do the trick.

Comment: maybe with the SubItems collection ?
ListViewItem item1 = new ListViewItem("item1",0);
item1.SubItems.Add("1");